# Horizontal scroll not working as expected

Tags: html, css

Hello I am trying to implement horizontal scrolling (using scroll bars)but I can't get it to work properly
I have 2 divs 1 for scroll and 1 main div I want to display the items on the main div but when I do that the whole div scrolls, instead of only the items. How can I get this to work?

scroll div

```
<div class="scrolling-wrapper">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

main div

```
<div class="main">

</div>
```

CSS

```
.scrolling-wrapper {
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}


   .item {
        display: inline-block;
        align-self: flex-start;
        background-color: var(--pampas);
        border-radius: 10px;
        flex-shrink: 0;
        height: 269px;
        margin-left: 210px;
        margin-top: 13px;
        width: 200px;
    }

.main {
  align-items: center;
  background-color: white;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: auto;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  min-height: 1080px;
  padding: 26px 0;
  width: 1920px;
}
```

[image: Here is how it looks right now]

Here is how it looks right now.

Thank you <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want all the items to scroll together (i.e. not each one individually) but only inside `div.scrolling-wrapper` which is a child of `div.main`.

This only works if you restrict the width of `div.scrolling-wrapper`.

You most likely need

```css
.scrolling-wrapper {
   width: 100%;
   /* you can also use max-width instead */
}
```

The `100%` refer to the parent's width, in this case that of `div.main`. This is necessary because you have `display:flex` set on `div.main` which has the effect that its child `div.scrolling-wrapper` gets  the sum of its children' (the `.item`s) widths as its default width.

As a sidenote: Please mind that the following rules related to flexbox that you set on `.item`:

```css
   align-self: flex-start;
   flex-shrink: 0;
```

don't have any effect unless there is some rule that you didn't mention in your original post that sets `.scrolling-wrapper` to `display:flex`.

Comment: Also, try adding `min-width: 0` to `.item`

Comment: Sorry about the late checkmark